# xcode-cloud-assertion failures when testing Xcode Source Editor Extension

Tags: xcode, macos, apple-id

So I have a bare-bones Xcode project with an Xcode Source Editor Extension target attached. I'd like to [test the thing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit/testing_your_source_editor_extension), so I hit run. A new instance of Xcode pops up, where my extension should appear in the Editor menu, but there's nothing there. The logs show the following lines (among other things):

```
2023-01-20 13:44:24.240562-0800 Xcode[2203:46831] [xcode-cloud-assertion] ❌❌❌ Assertion failure #0 in Failed SW AuthKit for: <private>
2023-01-20 13:44:24.249980-0800 Xcode[2203:46831] [xcode-cloud-assertion] ❌❌❌ Assertion failure #0 in Failed to authenticate account: <private> error: <private>
```

For context, I'm running the following:

- macOS 12.6.2
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- Xcode 14.0 (14A309)

I'm not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program, and I've never used Xcode Cloud.

It's also worth noting that when I go to **Reports > Cloud**, I get **Analyzing workspace...** for a few minutes before **Could not load Xcode Cloud data** pops up (same issue as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707699)). I get similar behavior across all projects, including brand new ones. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with these log messages above, but I kind of hope it does.

I've tried the following:

- Removing and adding my Apple ID in Xcode, restarting my MacBook in between
- Deleting my development certificates

The main thing is that I'd like to be able to test my source editor extension. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The problem is [XcodeKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit), which [isn't set to sign out of the box](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670068). I was able to fix it by setting it to Embed & Sign under `General > Frameworks and Libraries > XcodeKit.framework` (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxpzE.jpg)).